Modify API gateway response
How can I send custom error message using API gateway
Presently, the DENY responses are returned with:

"User is not authorized to access this resource with an explicit deny"

I want to change the message to "Not allowed" in template yaml.

Related documentation here.

To customize the error message for REST APIs in API gateway the following steps should help:

Sign in to the API Gateway console

Choose a REST API

In the main navigation pane, choose Gateway responses

Choose the required response type, refer gateway response types for API gateway AWS doc for more details

Under Response templates, update message in the Template body editor with the required customized message


The above steps were referred from the AWS doc - set up gateway response for a REST API using API gateway console
Additionally if lambda authorizer is being used, a custom error message could be passed in the context output, referring this AWS doc. The error message in the context output could then be referred in the response templates body as $context.authorizer.errorMessage.
